# StringReplace fails to replace all instances of a string

Tags: delphi, replace

The Dephi 7 help manual says of StringReplace...

> Returns a string with occurrences of one substring replaced by another substring...
>
> If Flags does not include rfReplaceAll, StringReplace only replaces the first occurrence of OldPattern in S. Otherwise, StringReplace replaces all instances of OldPattern with NewPattern.

The statement that, "Otherwise, StringReplace replaces all instances of OldPattern with NewPattern" appears to be a BOGUS statement, for in the example below, instances of "aa" remain even after I instruct the function to "replace all instances of 'aa' (OldPattern) with 'a' (NewPattern)"!

```
StringReplace('aaa aaa','aa','a',[rfReplaceAll]);
```

If the Delphi manual was accurate, then I should be getting 'a a' as the final result. Unfortunately, I am getting 'aa aa'.  Clearly not all instances of "OldPattern" ('aa') were replaced.

Is this a bug, or simply a misleading/inaccurate description for the function?

Comment: All instances of `aa` that **existed in the original string** were replaced; it doesn't recurse.

Comment: Note that if it did what you assumed, you could cause an infinite loop  with `StringReplace('aaa aaa', 'aa', 'aa', [rfReplaceAll])`!

Comment: No it would not cause an infinite loop. It would return 'a a'.  The first interation you would have 'aa aaa'. The next, 'a aaa'.  The next, 'a aa', and finally, 'a a'.  I see no infinite loop.

Comment: @user1527613, if the `StringReplace` would be recursive, the example from Blorgbeard's comment would cause an infinite loop because you'd replace string `aa` with the same string `aa` and there wouldn't be way out.

Answer (score 15):

You have misunderstood the documentation. If the act of replacing an instance of the search string with the replacement happens to create another instance of the search string, it is not searched again. The search continues from the end of the replacement text.

The function searches for all instances of the target string *in the input string `S`*. The input string is not modified. To get the output you expected, it would have to search for instances of the target string in the result, not just in the input.

Imagine if the search and replacement strings were identical. The function might never return because each time it found its target and replaced it, it would find yet another copy of the target text.

Answer (score 4):

Your example is correct, and Rob has explained why. Here's how it works, though. :-)

The first thing StringReplace finds is

```
aaa aaa
^
```

which is at index `1` in the string.

It replaces the first `aa` with `a`, so the return value is

```
a
```

It then increments its position to right after the first match, which is

```
aaa aaa
  ^
```

The next characters are `a`, which don't match the replace. Add this character to the return value, and move forward

Result:

```
aa
```

Position in source string

```
aaa aaa
   ^
```

This is the space character, and doesn't match, so it adds to result and moves forward:

Result:

```
aa
```

Position in source

```
aaa aaa
    ^
```

We have a match, so we replace it and move past it in the source. Now we're at

Result

```
aa a
```

Position in source

```
aaa aaa
      ^
```

There's no match remaining, so we just add the rest of the characters to our result and we're done. The function result is

```
aa aa
```

So the code is working as designed, and the documentation is correct. :-)

Comment: Your walkthough is a little off.. You are not skipping the match when you find one, you're just moving to the next character. And you don't seem to be adding characters when you say you do. Your first two matches imply that "aaa" matches "aa" twice, if that was true StringReplace('aaa', 'aa', 'hello') would result in `hellohello`, not `helloa`.

Comment: Like Blorgbeard says, after position 1, with gives a head of "aa", the pointer should go to position 3, which leaves a tail of "a aaa". Etc.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: You're right. I need to proofread better when it's late. :-) Thanks for the catch. (I also missed adding the remainder of the source to Result after the last match had been processed; fixed that while I was at it.)

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to replace all OldPattern with NewPattern.

```
function StringReplaceAll(S: string; const OldPattern, NewPattern: string;
  Flags: TReplaceFlags): string;
begin
  Flags := Flags + [rfReplaceAll];
  repeat
    Result := S;
    S := StringReplace(Result, OldPattern, NewPattern, Flags);
  until Result = S;
end;
```

This function do the replacement and check if it is still needed to be replaced , if so it will do the replacement again.